# Problems with the Unity text field

Tags: unity, c#, text

Let say I have this list and currently there are three animals inside the list.
These names below are displayed on the text field in the scene.

Cat

Bird

Goat

If there is a new animal is added to the list, for example a 'dog', 
the code will add 'dog' below the 'Goat' inside the text field above.
Now I have a problem when the same animal is added to the list. I don't know how to actually display the updated text field if the same type of animal is added to the list and will not messing up the text field or duplicating the same name inside the text field. Please help.

This is the code

```
foreach (var animalnames in newComp)
        {
            if((componentName.text.Length !=0)&&(animal.transform.name != animalnames.name))
            {
                componentName.text = oldName+('\n')+('\n')+('\n')+animal.transform.name;
            }
            if((componentName.text.Length !=0)&&(animal.transform.name == animalnames.name))
            {
                Debug.Log("same");
                animalnames.name = animal.transform.name;
                //componentName.text = ('\n')+animalnames.name;
            }
        }
        oldName = componentName.text;
```

Comment: I have 2 question. Is newComp a list? And what exactly do you want to do, like you don't want to show duplicate text or you wanna show duplicate text but at the bottom?

Comment: Yes, newComp is a list, and I want to make some sort of list of animals, and yes, I don't want to show duplicate text.

Comment: I see that @Xesenix solution worked for you. But I'll leave my suggestion as well.

You can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) here. To avoid saving duplicates, just use [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx) method to check the _text_ you want to add already exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use StringBuilder for creating text field content something like this:

```
// somewhere in component constructor
this.sb = new StringBuilder()
this.animalNamesList = new List<string>()

// when adding new name
if (!this.animalNamesList.Contains(name)) {
    this.animalNamesList.Add(name)
}


// and in update text field content
this.sb.clear()
foreach (string animalName in this.animalNamesList) {
    this.sb.AppendLine(animalName)
}
this.textField.text = this.sb.ToString()
```

Check more about String builder:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

and List:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the code is working except when I try to clear the string with this `this.sb.clear()`, it doesn't exist. Am I missing something?

Comment: did you create it in class constructor do you have 'this.sb = new StringBuilder()' somewhere?

Comment: If you are using C# 4.0 or higher compiler, you can use [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g. `text = string.Join("\n\n", newComp.Select(an => an.name))`, chaining select with `Distinct` if you want just distinct values.

Comment: @Xesenix I use 'this.sb = new StringBuilder()' when I'm initializing it, but it's solved now. I just use 'stringBuilder.Length = 0' to clear the list, but I still don't know how not to make the text field not displaying duplicate texts.

Comment: You guys are amazing! I use @Xesenix code and I use `Distinct` like @wondra suggested and it worked now. Thanks again :)

Comment: @user3132527 if you always use this: 
   `if (!this.animalNamesList.Contains(name)) {
        this.animalNamesList.Add(name)
    }`
for adding new elements they will be unique